# Tensorflow io import issue - missing module even if showing in pip freeze

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pyenv

I am trying to use tensorflow io to process mp3 audio files.
My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.

I created a new dedicated virtual environnement and activated it using pyenv :

```
pyenv virtualenv testtfio; pyenv local testtfio
```

I also upgraded pip as I thought it might cause the issue. Then I installed tensorflow_io :

```
pip install tensorflow_io
```

This generates installation of this package and all dependencies as I can see after using "pip freeze".
Then when I try to import tensorflow_io it shows :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_io'

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue was linked to Jupyter : I was using jupyter notebook in my new local environnement and it was running (I suppose from the pyenv global environment), but I forgot to install it in local virtualenv.

In order to solve the import issue in Jupyter notebook I just had to install Jupyter in my new local virtualenv.

```
pip install jupyter
```